# Accessing a file in Windows and Linux when working with JAVA+Eclipse

Tags: java, path

I'm doing some JAVA coding at home and at work. At home i have Linux, work, Windows. The rootpath to X file in Windows is c:\Documents And Settings\User\My Documents\Dropbox\file.xxx and in Linux is something like /media/My Documents/Dropbox/file.xxx

So, every time i edit in either system, i have to manually change the root of the file in a new File(FILEPATH) statement. Is there a workaround for this? I bet if the file root is relative to the project resource tree would do the trick, but that's an Eclipse based solution, not JAVA, i believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `System.getProperty("os.name")`? Then set the file path according to the OS. Another way would be to pass in the root as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of suggestions:

- A file in a subdirectory of the project is cross-platform portable (assuming, were you to launch the program outside of Eclipse you would maintain the file in the same location).
- Store the file in a similar relative path to your home directory (~ on Linux %USERPROFILE% on Windows) and use `System.getProperty("user.home")`
- Store the file on the class path and use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` or similar.

Comment: Yes, the project structure is the same in both systems, just changes the path to the project root directory. How do i load a file without mentioning the path to the root directory? Tried with "file.xxx" "/TheProject/res/file.xxx" and does not work.

Comment: The javadoc for File explains the conversion process in detail http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html. Essentially, given the structure /TheProject/res/file.xxx or on Windows C:\TheProject\res\file and assuming that in both cases the app is launched from the TheProject directory, `new File("res/file.xxx");` should get you the correct file reference.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `user.home` property to get the home directory of the current user:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```